# Implementing a toString method to print out a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having trouble with a project I have for my OOP class. I'm nearly finished, but still lack a toString method and a main method. Not really sure how to go about it and would appreciate any help. 
I want my `toString` method to function as follows:

> Returns a string representation of all the items stored in the list. A string representation of an empty list looks like `head--><--tail`
>   A string representation of a non-empty list looks like:
>   `head-->134<-->-8<-->42<-->1<--tail`

```
public class IntegerNode{

    private IntegerNode next;
    private IntegerNode prev;
    private int data;

    public IntegerNode(int data){
        next = next; 
        prev = prev;
        data = data;     
    }

    public int getData(){
        data = data;
        return this.data;   
    }

    public IntegerNode getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public IntegerNode getPrevious(){
        return prev;
    }

    public void setNext(IntegerNode in){
        prev = in;
    }

    public void setPrevious(IntegerNode in){
        prev = in;
    }

}
```

and here is what I have so far in my IntegerLinkedList class

```
public class IntegerLinkedList{

    private IntegerNode head;
    private IntegerNode tail;

    public IntegerLinkedList(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public void addFirst(int x){
        IntegerNode nH = new IntegerNode(x);
        if (head == null) {
            head = nH;
            tail = nH;
        }else{
            head.setPrevious(nH);
            nH.setNext(head);
            head = nH;

        }
    }

    public void addLast(int x){
        IntegerNode t = new IntegerNode(x);
        if (tail == null){
            head = t;
            tail = t;
        }else{
            tail.setNext(t);
            t.setPrevious(tail);
            tail = t;
        }
    }

    public int peekFirst(){
        return head.getData();
    }

    public int peekLast(){
        return tail.getData();
    }

    public String toString(){
        if (head == null && tail == null){
            String empty = "head--><--tail";
            return empty;
        }else{
            String h = "Head--> " + head;
            String t = tail + " <--Tail";
            String m = " <--> ";
           // while(IntegerNode.getNext() != null) 
           //}
           //return h + m + t;

        }
    }

    public int pollFirst(){
        int x = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
        head.setPrevious(null);
        return x;
    }

    public int pollLast(){
        int x = tail.getData();
        tail = tail.getPrevious();
        tail.setNext(null);
        return x;
    }

}
```

I'm thinking a while loop is the way to go here, but then again I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you do `data = data`.. but in your `toString()` method create a temporary `IntegerNode` and loop through from head to tail and stop when it is the tail... `appending the .getData()` to it each time`

Comment: In your code, `setNext()` is setting `prev = in`and `setPrev()` is also setting `prev = in`. is it right?

Comment: @Matputer Thank you sir. Good spot.

Comment: @3kings you're absolutely right! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to write it:

```
@Override  // <-- Annotate that you are overriding the toString() method
public String toString(){
    if (head == null && tail == null){
        String empty = "head--><--tail";
        return empty;
    }else{
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("Head-->");

       IntegerNode curr = head;
       sb.append(curr.getData());
       curr = curr.getNext();
       while(curr != null) {
           sb.append("<-->");
           sb.append(curr.getData());
           curr = curr.getNext();
       }
       sb.append("<--tail");
       return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you can simplify the logic to not have an outer if else:

```
@Override  // <-- Annotate that you are overriding the toString() method
public String toString(){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("Head-->");

   IntegerNode curr = head;

   if (curr == null)
   {
      sb.append("<--tail");
      return sb.toString();
   }

   sb.append(curr.getData());
   curr = curr.getNext();
   while(curr != null) {
       sb.append("<-->");
       sb.append(curr.getData());
       curr = curr.getNext();
   }
   sb.append("<--tail");

   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do this using just String instead?

Comment: @PaulDaniels Of course, just create a String in place of the StringBuilder and use += instead of append. Note you will have to convert the curr.getData() to a String.

Comment: You can also create a toString method for IntegerNode class as well. Then you've got some recursive toStringing going on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use a loop, because you want to iterate over data of unknown length. Michael Markidis wrote the answer more quickly than me, use his solution, however I would suggest some improvements to your code.

`String h = "Head--> " + head;` won't work, because head is an object `IntegerNode`, and you want to access its data like this `head.getData()` (also why do you assign `data = data;` in this method? It should only do return)

If you want to assign data in constructor that have the same name as field, use have to use `this` keyword to make clear what do you want to assign. Also assigning null `next` and `prev` has no meaning, so this code

```
public IntegerNode(int data){
    next = next; 
    prev = prev;
    data = data;     
}
```

should look like this

```
public IntegerNode(int data){
    this.data = data;     
}
```

or if you want to assign the previous and next node

```
public IntegerNode(int data, IntegerNode next, IntegerNode prev){
    this.next = next; 
    this.prev = prev;
    this.data = data;     
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely make changes.

Comment: Also, a copy/paste error in `setNext()`. It sets the `prev` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8+, [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) makes it easy.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("<-->", "head-->", "<--tail");
    for (IntegerNode node = this.head; node != null; node = node.getNext())
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(node.getData()));
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

If not using Java 8, a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is the right way to go.
  <sup>(Performs better than using `String` directly)</sup>

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("head-->");
    boolean sep = false;
    for (IntegerNode node = this.head; node != null; node = node.getNext()) {
        if (sep)
            buf.append("<-->");
        buf.append(node.getData());
        sep = true;
    }
    return buf.append("<--tail").toString();
}
```

In both cases, you use a [basic `for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) with a `node` variable to iterate through the list.

---

As for the rest of your code, you have some issues.

> ```
> public IntegerNode(int data){
>     next = next; 
>     prev = prev;
>     data = data;     
> }
> ```

Assigning `next` to `next` and `prev` to `prev` is meaningless.
Assigning the parameter to the field will only work if you qualify the field with `this.`, otherwise you're assigning the parameter to itself (meaningless).

```
public IntegerNode(int data){
    this.data = data;     
}
```

---

> ```
> public int getData(){
>     data = data;
>     return this.data;   
> }
> ```

Assigning `data` to `data` is meaningless.

```
public int getData(){
    return this.data;   
}
```

---

> ```
> public void setNext(IntegerNode in){
>     prev = in;
> }
> ```

Copy/paste error. You meant to assign to `next`.

```
public void setNext(IntegerNode in){
    next = in;
}
```

---

> ```
> public int pollFirst(){
>     int x = head.getData();
>     head = head.getNext();
>     head.setPrevious(null);
>     return x;
> }
>
> public int pollLast(){
>     int x = tail.getData();
>     tail = tail.getPrevious();
>     tail.setNext(null);
>     return x;
> }
> ```

These methods will throw `NullPointerException` when you poll the last<sup>1</sup> value from the list.
Add missing `if` statement.

```
public int pollFirst(){
    int x = head.getData();
    head = head.getNext();
    if (head == null)
        tail = null;
    else
        head.setPrevious(null);
    return x;
}

public int pollLast(){
    int x = tail.getData();
    tail = tail.getPrevious();
    if (tail == null)
        head = null;
    else
        tail.setNext(null);
    return x;
}
```

<sup>1) "last" refers to the "only remaining" value, not the "tail" value.</sup>